# Swing - JButton text does not respond to setText()

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have an action added to a JButton created, following is my code

```
    private void myButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
    txtResult.setText("");
    myButton.setText("Working ...");
    myButton.setEnabled(false);
    myButton.repaint();
    System.out.println("Doing Action ...");
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() { // some code inside that is memory intensive
        }
    });
    segmentButton.setText("Original Text");
    segmentButton.setEnabled(true);
}
```

While I am able to see the system out, my component is not getting updated at all, more over I am unable to update any other component on the JFrame as if the whole thread is blocked

Comment: `...as if the whole thread is blocked` It is. Swing is single threaded - placing some intensive code on the EDT using SwingUtilities will block Swing from updating. Use a separate thread or a SwingWorker

Comment: Thanks @copeg! I have added an answer based on your advice and mentioned you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer was that the main thread gets blocked due to the singular nature of swing main thread.

> "The Swing single-thread rule: Swing components and models should be
>   created, modified, and queried only from the event-dispatching
>   thread."

—Java Concurrency in Practice.
I have updated my code to accommodate the blocker code in a SwingWorker as described below

```
private void myButtonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
txtResult.setText("");
myButton.setText("Working ...");
myButton.setEnabled(false);
myButton.repaint();
System.out.println("Doing Action ...");
    SwingWorker worker = new SwingWorker() {
        @Override
        protected Object doInBackground() throws Exception {
            //Memory intensive code
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            segmentButton.setText("Original Text");
            segmentButton.setEnabled(true);
            super.done(); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }
    };
    worker.execute();
}
```

Thanks @copeg for putting me on the right direction.

Comment: @AndrewThompson Done, Thanks for the advice